# symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 in xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I got this error when trying to running app in simulator. And I'm using this library. https://github.com/donobono/DoImagePickerController. How can I solve this problem?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DoImagePickerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NewActivityVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which simulator (eg. iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, etc.) are you trying to run it on?

Comment: in simulator 5s, also with device 6 plus not working. @l'L'l

Comment: It worked fine for me right out of the box. Maybe try re-downloading the project and try again; try to clean before building. Check the SDK you have selected also (mine was set at Latest 9.1)

Comment: @l'L'l everything working now after I installing it through cocoapods.